# How to calculate the weight of the stocks using the linear regression?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, regression, pairs-trading, spread

I do a simple example with the follow three series(stocks prices):

```
a = 1, 1.2, 1.8, 1.3, 0.9, 2
b = 56, 58, 63, 61.5, 57.6, 58
c = 105.6, 110, 106.9, 103, 101.2, 107
```

ok, so let assume those series are the prices of the three stocks, named **A**, **B** and **C**.

Now, I do the linear regression doing:

```
mod = lm(a ~ b + c + 0)
```

the result of the linear model is:

```
Call:
lm(formula = a ~ b + c + 0)

Coefficients:
        b          c  
 0.030570  -0.004095  

> mod$residuals
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
-0.2795238 -0.1226474  0.3118110 -0.1583030 -0.4464512  0.6650691
```

Now we know the coefficients of **b** and **c** and here I have a doubt regarding, how can I understand reading these coefficients the weight of the stocks I need to buy.

With the weight I mean, example:

```
A: 10 stocks
B: 2 stocks
C: 16 stocks
```

I would like to create this spread and calculate the correct number of stocks.

**IMPORTANT:** This is only an example, I know that I need more tests to check the stability etc etc but with this example I only would like to understand:

**How can I calculate the number of the stocks reading the linear regression coefficients?**

Thank you!

Comment: Seven of your 11 questions on here have been closed. Given the sheer volume of warnings you've received, you should know by now what's considered appropriate level of material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you measure something that you actually do not look out for. Your regression tries to explain prices of stock A by using a linear combination of stocks B and C. The coefficients tell you the fraction of stocks you need to have in stocks B and C in order to arrive at the predicted price of stock A. Thus, 0.031 shares of stock B plus 0.0041 shares SHORT of stock C will output the predicted price of stock A. I doubt that is what you want UNLESS you are convinced that prices of stock B and C OVER TIME are a good predictor for prices in stock A. Generally I advise, however, you work with log returns and not absolute stock prices. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I know what the linear regression does, but with this question i'm asking how can apply the coefficients to my trades, I do a stupid example..... as you saw I have these coefficients: (0.030570  -0.004095) The question is that I can buy or sell 0.03 or 0.004 of a stock, I can but 1 2 3 4 etc etc stocks i can easily calculate the weight if i do a linear regression with two stock, mod = lm(a~b+0) but in this case i have 2 stocks (on the right) so what is the hedge ratio of this spread? I would like to know something like: A: 1 - B: 20 - C: 30

Comment: I need to understand how many stocks I need to buy or sell (it is not the point now ... the type of the trade). Know the coefficients are how  many trade I need to buy for each A, but i can't buy 0.0041 stocks. So the question is how can I bring these numbers to the real trading number of stocks.

Comment: calculate the lowest common denominator, that is your hedge ratio: In this example short 1 stock of stock C and buy 7.5 of stock B to hedge 250 units of stock A. Those are rough figures but about what your LM outputs.